# Using a rotation matrix to convert euler units to 360 degrees

Tags: android, sensors

In Android, I am using the accelerometer and magnetic field sensor to calculate spatial positioning, as shown in the code below. The getRotationMatrix method generates values that are in real-world units with azimuth, pitch and roll. Azimuth and roll give values in the range of 0 to 180 or 0 to -180. Pitch however gives values from 0 to 90 or 0 to -90. That's a problem for my app because in my app I need to determine unique locations regardless how the device is oriented. With roll, you can have 2 locations with the same value.

I need to apply a matrix transformation that remaps the sensor values to values that range from 0 to 360 degrees (actually, 360 wouldn't be valid since it's the same as 0 and anything close to 360 would result in a number like 359.99999...)

I am not a mathematician and don't know how to use matrixes, let alone use them in Android but I am aware that this is what is required to get the 0 to 360 degree conversion. It would be nice if the matrix also took care of the azimuth and roll as well so that they also produce values from 0 to 360 but if that isn't possible, that's fine since unique positions can still be derived from their sensor values. Any suggestions how how I create this matrix transformation?

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
  try
  {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
      accelerometerValues = event.values;
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
      magneticFieldValues = event.values;

    if ((accelerometerValues != null) && (magneticFieldValues != null))
    {

      float[] R = new float[9];
      float I[] = new float[9];

      boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, accelerometerValues, magneticFieldValues);

      if (success)
      {
        float[] values = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(R, values);

        // Convert from radians to degrees if preferred.
        values[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[0]); // Azimuth
        values[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[1]); // Pitch
        values[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[2]); // Roll
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The raw event values for the pitch do not give you unique values as you rotate the device 360 degrees, so I highly doubt any matrix transformation is going to produce the results I am after. Maybe I am using the wrong sensors.

Comment: Do you mean spatial positioning of the device?

Comment: Yes. You can take the device and rotate it in any direction and come up with a unique location. Pitch is currently the problem because the getRotationMatrix can give you the same value if tilted in the opposite direction.

Comment: You can use the inclination in my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477133/how-to-use-android-sensor-event-to-determine-if-device-is-facing-up-or-down/14767005#14767005. The inclination is independent of device orientation, ie portrait, landscape or any rotation in between. Try to understand what is the Rotation Matrix mathematically and how it is calculated will let you get the device positioning, facing and rotational movement just by calculate some trig function on members of the rotation matrix.

Comment: You line of code int inclination = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(R[8])));  does not generate unique positions as you rotate the sensor 360 degrees. It does give me a 0 to 180 degree transformation and that is still better than 0 to 90.

Comment: I just tested my app and realize that. I will fix that if I have time, in the mean time you can combine the inclination value and pitch to get a unique value.

Comment: I actually thought of that after posting my comment. I can't use remapCoordinate because of the API version but I can still remap it manually. Thanks for you suggestion. It now gives me unique values around the pitch. A matrix transformation solution would be better though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24808/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-androiddev)